# insert record in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a file called functions.php which contains many functions, now what i want to do is store whatever those functions return in a database. What i am currently doing is that i am starting a database connection in every function and closing it as well in every connection. Which what it does it that, it stores the data in database but it also increments the rows in my database. each value returned by a function is being stored in a different row. I want them to be in the same row. What should i do?
This is my code so far,

```
function h3() {

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$url=$_POST["urlo"];

$counter = 0;
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('h3') as $element){
    $counter++;
}

echo $counter;

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO results(h3) VALUES ('$counter')");
mysqli_close($con);
}

function paragraph() {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$url=$_POST["urlo"];

$counter = 0;
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('p') as $element){
    $counter++;
}

echo $counter;
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO results(p) VALUES ('$counter')");
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: If you want results in the same row, you need to UPDATE, not INSERT, each time.

Comment: Well first of all, if youre trying to store things all on the same row, you will need to use UPDATE, not INSERT. Or possibly an ON DUPLICATE KEY clause with an INSERT statement. 

Why would you not want them stored on separate rows? Does each function have its own field in the database?

Comment: And please, for the love of science, indent your code.

Comment: Sorry about the code, and Yes, each function has its own field in the DB

Comment: Well Answer me *Why are you using* **mysqli_close($con);** *twice?* Use it at the end of your code!